# Can Vertx executeBlocking be used on a list?

Tags: vert.x

Trying to process a list of long running jobs in a vertx way

One would hope one could do something like:

- use the executeBlocking to process the long running job in an async manner
- use the composite future to wait for the futures to complete

I'm aware this approach does not work .. the list of Futures is not complete before the code drops into the CompositeFuture.

Is there a executeBlocking approach or does one have to use either the eventbus, vertx utils that support lists?

```
    java.util.ArrayList futureList = new ArrayList()
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
            vertx.executeBlocking({ future ->
            int id = i
            println "Running " + id
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
            println "Thread done " + id
            future.complete()
        }, true , { res ->
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                print "."
            } else {
                print "x"
            }
        })
    }

    CompositeFuture.join(futureList).setHandler({ ar ->
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                System.err.println "all threads should be done.."
            }
    })
```

Results in .. "all threads should be done" printing early

```
    Running 84
    Running 87
    Running 87
    Running 95
    all threads should be done..
    done.
    Thread done 3
    Thread done 36
    Thread done 3
```

Thread done 0

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `futureList` is empty so `CompositeFuture.join(futureList)` is completed immediately.

Change your example like this:

```
java.util.ArrayList futureList = new ArrayList()
for (i = 0; i < 100; i ++){
  Future jobFuture = Future.future()
  futureList.add(jobFuture)
  vertx.executeBlocking({ future ->
    int id = i
    println "Running " + id
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000)
    println "Thread done " + id
    future.complete()
  }, true , { res ->
    if (res.succeeded()) {
      print "."
    } else {
      print "x"
    }
    jobFuture.complete()
  })
}
```

Notice the `jobFuture` creation:

```
  Future jobFuture = Future.future()
  futureList.add(jobFuture)
```

As well as completion:

```
    jobFuture.complete()
```

Now the `CompositeFuture.join(futureList)` handler will be executed only after all jobs complete.